# How to send parameters to existing hidden fragment from activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, communication

I have a MainActivity with a NavigationDrawer. When I click on the navigation, a new fragment is created. By clicking on the next navigation point, the old is removed and the new is added with a transaction.

Sometimes i open a new window within a navigation point. in this case i hide the old fragment and add a new fragment. now my problem:

I have a fragmentA with an editText. When I click on this editText field a new fragmentB will be opened. The old fragmentA will be hidden. FragmentB has a list with items. When I click on one of this items I want to close this fragmentB and fill the value of the listItem in the editText of fragmentA.
I tried many things, but it's not working.
I transfer the listitem information to the MainActivity with a Communicator interface. That works. However, the way from the Mainactivity to the fragmentA is the problem.
I can't put the item value with Bundle arguments because the fragment A is already there. I tried to call a public function which exists in fragmentA, but everytime I want to call this function from the MainActivity it is not possible, because there is no such function. I have no idea for updating the editText in fragmentA and hope for help.

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: If this wall of text had some formatting, that'd be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok let me see if I understand, you have the MainActivity and 2 fragments A and B. When someting in your MainActivity fires the transaction, you want to hide fragment B, and show fragment A. But also, transfer some info that lives in fragment B to fragment A, am I right?

Then, I understood you already have the info in MainActivity that you transfered from B using an interface (which is the correct way to do it). Now you can't pass that info to fragment A.

Before commit the transaction, you had to instantiate the fragment A, so after commit you can just call a public method in A to send your info, right? If that's not working it's because may be you're trying to send it before it exists on screen.

Anyway, try to share some code, to figure out what happens.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have found the solution. The public method couldn't work because I forgot to cast the fragment. I use a FragmentStack and I get the fragmentA from the FragmentStack. Without casting it I couldn't call the public method. Now it works. I only had to cast the last element of the FragmentStack to FragmentA.

Answer (score 0):

I used to communicate via the Activity (Activity registers listener to Fragment 1 and Fragment 1 calls the listener methods, then the Activity calls Fragment 2 etc.). This works but is very cumbersome and inflexible). Since I moved to a message bus I never looked back. With a message bus you can send from any component to any other component in your application using the publish - subscribe pattern (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern).

I'm using EventBus (https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) but there are alternative implementations like Otto (https://github.com/square/otto). EventBus is very stable (didn't have a single crash in any of my apps and I have lots of users) and reliable.

IMO using a message bus compared to using listeners and callback methods has the following advantages:

- A message is always an object forcing the developer to code object oriented compared to the more functional listener method calls
- It decouples the different components. Publisher and subscribers don't have to know about each other. Also the Activity (in your case) doesn't have to know anything about the communication between the fragments. Decoupling the components will make your code much leaner and easier to read (and maintain).
- It can be used by arbitrary components. E.g. I replaced all LocalBroadcastManager calls by EventBus messages (EventBus is MUCH faster that using a LocalBroadcastManager). Being able to communicate between arbitrary components is especially convenient if the components can't access each other directly (like a Dialog and a Preference object).

Of course one should mention the drawback. It's probably "easier" to introduce memory leaks using the publish - subscribe pattern since an object is sent as is and could easily be referenced longer than it should.

I'd nevertheless recommend to rethink your approach and consider using a message bus instead of calling methods back and forth between fragments and your Activity.

Comment: Thank you, sounds very interesting. I will try this in the future.